# NHibernate Fluent Mapping a String Property to another Table's column

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a table in the database that is used only for holding some ID's descriptions:

```
TABLE SomeClass
- Columns
- ClassTypeID INT CONSTRAINT etc

TABLE SomeClassTypes
- ClassTypeID INT IDENTITY
- Description NVARCHAR
```

It's done like this so it's easy for users to insert/remove new types.
I want to get a report of all of `SomeClass`, but I'd like to have a string property to hold the description from the other table:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public virtual int SomeClassID { get; set; }
    public virtual int ClassTypeID { get; set; }
    public virtual string DescriptionType { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClassMap : ClassMapping<SomeClass>
{
    public SomeClassMap()
    {
        Table("SomeClassTable");
        Property(p => p.SomeClassID, map => 
        { 
            map.Column("SomeClassID");
            map.Generator(Generators.Identity);
        });
        Property(p => p.ClassTypeID, map => map.Column("ClassTypeID"));
        //Other properties here

        Property(p => p.DescriptionType, ?); //This line
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use joined table.

```
public class SomeClassMap : ClassMapping<SomeClass>
{
public SomeClassMap()
{
    Table("SomeClassTable");
    Property(p => p.SomeClassID, map => 
    { 
        map.Column("SomeClassID");
        map.Generator(Generators.Identity);
    });
    Property(p => p.ClassTypeID, map => map.Column("ClassTypeID"));
    //Other properties here

    Join("SomeClassTypes", m => 
        {
            m.KeyColumn("ClassTypeId");
            m.Fetch.Join();
            m.Map(x => x.DescriptionType).Column("Description");
        })
}
}
```

**EDITED**

If you use fluent mapping built in NHibernate, try this:

```
public class SomeClassMap : ClassMapping<SomeClass>
{
    public SomeClassMap()
    {
        Table("SomeClassTable");
        Property(p => p.SomeClassID, map => 
        { 
            map.Column("SomeClassID");
            map.Generator(Generators.Identity);
        });
        Property(p => p.ClassTypeID, map => map.Column("ClassTypeID"));
        //Other properties here

        Property(p => p.DescriptionType, ?); //This line
        Join("SomeClassTypes", m => 
            {
                m.Key(k => k.Column("ClassTypeId"));
                m.Fetch(FetchKind.Join);
                m.Property(x => x.DescriptionType).Column("Description");
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do like this but intellisense doesn't show any of these functions. I've checked the version and it's the `3.3.2`, and the latest I found in NHForge is `3.3.3`. Maybe I'm missing something, but what do I need to use `KeyColumn`, `Fetch.Join()` or even `Map().Column()`?

Comment: Could you show your mapping with Join clause? Plz, pay attention,  that methods KeyColumn, Fetch.Join and Map for the joined table must be called inside the lambda expression of the Join,

Comment: By the way, which version of FluentNHibernate do you use? (my version is 1.2.0)

Comment: I think that's the problem, I'm using a `NHibernate.dll` that already was with the project (I'm inheriting a big project), but it appears the mapping was done the fluent way. For example, my `Join(string, IJoinMapper)`'s `IJoinMapper` doesn't have `KeyColumn()`, only `Key(System.Action<IKeyMapper>)`.

Comment: Try use methods m.Key() instead of m.KeyColumn(), m.Fetch(FetchKind.Join) instead of m.Fetch.Join(). It seems that in version 3.2 some parts of FluentNHibernate library was included into NHibernate library itself.

Comment: This article might be helpful in your case: http://notherdev.blogspot.ru/2012/01/mapping-by-code-join.html